# Storing a hmac key in Android keystore

Tags: java, android, cryptography, keystore, hmac

I am using the below code to create a hmac key and returning it as a string.

```
KeyGenerator keyGen = null;
    try {
        keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SecretKey key = keyGen.generateKey();
    byte[] encoded = key.getEncoded();
    String s=Base64.encodeToString(encoded, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Log.i("Hmac key before encrypt",s);

    try {
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        keystore.load(null, null);
        KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keystore.getEntry("temp", null);
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) privateKeyEntry.getCertificate().getPublicKey();

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        byte[] cipherBytes = cipher.doFinal(encoded);

        return Base64.encodeToString(cipherBytes,Base64.DEFAULT);


    } catch (UnrecoverableEntryException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

How can I store this in the android keystore?. I have tried using the below code:

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        keyStore.load(null);

        KeyStore.ProtectionParameter param = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("test".toCharArray());
        keyStore.setEntry("key1",hmacKey,param);
```

I get an errors no matter what format hmacKey is in: String/Bytes or `javax.crypto.SecretKey`. Below are the errors:
In case of passing Key `hmacKey`:

```
Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'java.security.Key', required: 'java.security.KeyStore.Entry'
```

Same in cases where I pass a string or byte array.

If I typecast the parameter to `java.security.KeyStore.Entry`, it still doesn't work.

Is this the correct way of doing so? Can anyone give pointers as to how the HMAC key can be stored in the keystore using an alias. How can convert the hmack key to `java.security.KeyStore.Entry` format?

Comment: Sorry for being ambiguous. Edited the question

Comment: Can't you just store the `key` as generated above? I see a lot of fluff in the question. This doesn't seem to be a MCSE.

Comment: No it cant be stored as such. I am currently using shared preferences to store this key. Not sure whether about the security aspect there, that's why I wanted to store it in the key store. The first part of the code works absolutely fine and I can create a hmack key as well as return it. Its the part where I am trying to store it in the android key store with an alias that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The Android key store was created to allow you to use asymmetric keys and symmetric keys *outside* your application code. As specified [in the training material](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html):

> Key material never enters the application process. When an application performs cryptographic operations using an Android Keystore key, behind the scenes plaintext, ciphertext, and messages to be signed or verified are fed to a system process which carries out the cryptographic operations. If the app's process is compromised, the attacker may be able to use the app's keys but will not be able to extract their key material (for example, to be used outside of the Android device).

So the idea of generating the key inside the application code - and thus outside the key store - is not a good idea. How to generate a secret key inside the key store is defined for HMAC keys in the [API for the `KeyGenParameterSpec` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.html):

```
KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(
         KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_HMAC_SHA256, "AndroidKeyStore");
keyGenerator.initialize(
         new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder("key2", KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN).build());
SecretKey key = keyGenerator.generateKey();
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
mac.init(key);
...

// The key can also be obtained from the Android Keystore any time as follows:
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
keyStore.load(null);
key = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey("key2", null);
```

Other key types can be found [in the `KeyProperties` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyProperties.html)

Comment: The thing is that I am receiving the encrypted hmack key from the server and therefore I just need to store it in the safest option available on the device. I will later extract it, decrypt using the private key and use it as required. I believed that the keystore will be safer than shared preferences, therefore wanted to use it to store the key. Thats where I am stuck and so I am using shared preferences for now. Any idea on how I can save the externally generated hmac in the keystore? Also thanks Maarten for constantly looking into this.

Comment: What about wrapping that key with a key that is in the store?

Comment: Not sure how to do that, if you mean typecasting it to a keystore entry, that doesn't work. Also at any point of time I will only have a public/private keypair in my keystore. Along with that I wanted to store the hmac key.

Comment: @Sid what you should do is get the HMAC key from the server and import it into the Android KeyStore. Don't bother encrypting it yourself, Android KeyStore will take care of securing it far better than you could. See the KeyProtection documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyProtection.html) for an example of how to import an HMAC key into Android KeyStore, and how to use it.

Comment: A note here: wrapping a key is a cryptographic operation that is available from the Java cipher class (`Cipher.WRAP`).

Comment: @divegeek If you can build an answer out of that with code then I would certainly upvote it. I don't have an Android environment ready, if a HMAC key can be stored this way then that's definitely the most direct answer possible.